# Automapper ignore just one collection attribute

Tags: c#, collections, automapper

```
public class ObjectA
{
    string abc {get; set;}
}

public class ObjectB
{
    string abc {get; set;}
    string bla {get; set;}
}

public class A
{
    public string x { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ObjectA> CollectionA {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
    public string x { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Object B> CollectionB { get; set; }
}



cfg.CreateMap<A, B>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CollectionB, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CollectionA));
```

Hello, i want to keep the Collection but ignoring bla String inside, how can i achieve this?

I imagine i have to do something like:
.ForSourceMember(x => x.CollectionB, opt => opt.Ignore());

Searched in the automapper docs, but couldn't find a way to do this with collections.
Can someone help me in this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that i dont need to map the collection object attribute itself. Just need to maintain my previous mapping, like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<A, B>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CollectionB, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CollectionA))
```

And objects relation, like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<ObjectB, ObjectA>()
    .ForSourceMember(src => src.bla, dest => dest.Ignore());
```

That way automapper resolves the collection! 
Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Add a mapping from `ObjectA` to `ObjectB` and automapper will use that.

Automapper also doesn't need explicit mappings from `IEnumerable<ObjectA>` to `IEnumerable<ObjectB>` - just the initial `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` - it will infer the rest (obviously you will still need your `A` to `B` mapping in the example above however because they have their own properties).

Comment: Im facing:
CollectionB ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.